# Call a Function in Another Frame (WxPython)

Tags: python, wxpython

In my wxpython app, I have a parent frame and a child frame. When I click on a button inside the child frame, I want it to send some data (list, string etc.) to the  parent frame, close itself, show the parent and finally call a function in the parent frame. How can I do that? (especially function calling)

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**

Comment: you should mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, rather than edit your question to say 'solved'

Comment: Ok. You are right. But İf I solve the problem by myself, I think I can edit it to "solved" and explain what I did, right?

Comment: Add it as an answer. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the button click generate an event containing the data. Then add an event handler to the parent frame that extracts the data from the event and calls the function. The wxPython wiki has a [tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) that covers events. The wx documentation also has an [event handling overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_eventhandlingoverview.html#eventhandlingoverview).

Comment: Your answer seems the solution. So I had the button click generate an event containing the data. But How can I capture this data with an event handler inside my parent frame?

Comment: To use that method, you'd need to use PostEvent, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pubsub to do that too: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Or you can just use a subclass of a Dialog instead and show it modally. Or you could use PostEvent to pass the event. There's an example here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Another method that I just thought of would be to use a socket server or similar and post your data to that and have your program check the server for new data. That's pretty convoluted for this use case though.